# why I couldn't see the referenced dll module hosted by a process

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I create a new console application called 'ProcessManipulator' and referenced a private assembly called "CarLibrary.dll"( I created it before ProcessManipulator), then I added reference by associating CarLibrary with ProcessManipulator and added `using CarLibrary;` and started to use CarLibrary's types inside. And then run the console application

Below is the function that I use to probe each modules hosted the current process:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Car c = new Car(); // Car type is from CarLibrary
   c.Run();  
   Console.WriteLine("***** Enter PID of process to investigate *****");
   Console.Write("PID: ");
   string pID = Console.ReadLine();
   int theProcID = int.Parse(pID);
   EnumModsForPid(theProcID);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
static void EnumModsForPid(int pID)
{
   Process theProc = null;
   try
   {
      theProc = Process.GetProcessById(pID);
   }
   catch (ArgumentException ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      return;
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Here are the loaded modules for: {0}", theProc.ProcessName);
   ProcessModuleCollection theMods = theProc.Modules;
   foreach (ProcessModule pm in theMods)
   {
      string info = $"-> Mod Name: {pm.ModuleName}";
      Console.WriteLine(info);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("************************************\n");
}
```

so I typed  current process's ID(check ProcessManipulator's PID in task manager), to my surprise, I didn't see `CarLibrary.dll`, why it didn't appear in the list?

Comment: You'll see the unmanaged DLLs being used by the process.  Not a .NET assembly, the OS doesn't know anything about them.  They are just data.

Comment: @HansPassant   I can see some dll as ` ProcessManipulator.exe, mscorlib.ni.dll, MSCOREE.dll` etc, so why I can see `ProcessManipulator.exe` but not `CarLibrary.dll`? is `mscorlib.ni.dll` unmanaged dll?